# clojure uberjar throwing errors when run on openjdk

Tags: clojure, java, uberjar

I have written a clojure app which takes an option to encrypt or decrypt a file, along with source and destination filenames, and does the specified operations.  I developed the app in a virtualbox vm, running xubuntu 13, using clojure-1.5.1 and oracle's Java SE 7 JDK.  Everything works great in that environment, but when I copy the uberjar to the host system, which runns Xubuntu 12.10 using openjdk/jre 7, I get some different behavior, in terms of cli parsing.

1) The app should print the usage banner if no options are specified.  This works as it should under the development environment, but under openjdk, a NullPointerException is thrown.

2) The -v option should print the build version of the app.  Again, this works fine under the devel environment, but under openjdk/Xubuntu-12.10, an exception is thrown stating that -v is an invalid option.

Here is the function (called from -main): that handles cli parsing:

```
(defn parse-cli 
    "Parses command line arguments then calls functions based on those arguments.  Returns a String or nil if successful." 
    [args]
        (let [[opts files banner] 
          (cli args
              ["-h" "--help" "Print this help message." :flag true :default false]
              ["-v" "--version" "Print build number." :flag true :default false]
              ["-e" "--encrypt" "Encrypt source file" :flag true :default false]
              ["-d" "--decrypt" "Decrypt source file" :flag true :default false] 
              ["-k" "--keyfile" "Path to keyfile" :default "./keyfile"])]

            (cond (or (true? (:help opts)) (zero? (count args))) banner
                  (true? (:version opts)) (implementation-version)
                   :else (let [sfile (first files)
                    dfile (second files)
                    cryptoVec (get-cipher-key (:keyfile opts))]

                    (cond (true? (:encrypt opts)) (if (nil? sfile) "No input file specified" 
                                                        (if (nil? dfile) "No outputfile specified." 
                                                            (encrypt-file sfile dfile (first cryptoVec) (second cryptoVec))))
                            (true? (:decrypt opts)) (if (nil? sfile) "No input file specified" 
                                                    (if (nil? dfile) "No outputfile specified." 
                                                            (decrypt-file sfile dfile (first cryptoVec) (second cryptoVec))))
                            :else "No operation specified.")))))
```

Following is the full exception trace when the uberjar is run with no arguments:

```
satch@Ziggy-lin:/media/satch/DATA/.crypto$ java -jar cryptfile.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeConstructor(Reflector.java:180)
at clojure_crypt_file.core$decrypt_file.invoke(core.clj:40)
at clojure_crypt_file.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:81)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
at clojure_crypt_file.core.main(Unknown Source)
```

And the trace when running the app with the -v option:

```
satch@Ziggy-lin:/media/satch/DATA/.crypto$ java -jar cryptfile.jar -v
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: '-v' is not a valid argument
    at clojure.tools.cli$apply_specs.invoke(cli.clj:72)
    at clojure.tools.cli$cli.doInvoke(cli.clj:130)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:486)
    at clojure_crypt_file.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:61)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure_crypt_file.core.main(Unknown Source)
```

The rest of the app functionality works as expected under both environments.

I assume the problems arise from differences between openjdk7's jre and oracle's SE 7 jre, but beyond that I am clueless.  Specifically, I would like to find a way to work around these differences, if that is indeed the problem.

Comment: Just to clarify, I did check md5sums when copying from guest to host and they checked out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after recompiling, the app now works in both environments.  I did change the condition (false? (count args)) to (nil? args), but according to the docs, that should work either way (and did in the devel environment).  I did nothing to -v cli option, yet the app exhibits identical and correct behavior in both environments now.  Things like this are why computer science is a love/hate thing. :)